# Putting the antecedents after the pronouns!

Tags: grammar, grammaticality-in-context

Is it right to place a pronoun and then place the name: as is shown in the below sentence:

> - A few weeks before **he** died, **my father** gave me an old cigar box filled with faded letters.

Or it should always be put this way:

> - A few weeks before **my father** died, **he** gave me an old cigar box filled with faded letters.

Are they both right and acceptable?

Comment: Perfectly normal. An instance of [cataphora](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cataphora)

Comment: And in that case, the nouns become postcedents or simply referents.

Answer (score 2):

There is absolutely nothing wrong with either formulation. The problem with pronouns is that it is not always clear to which noun they refer but in the example quoted it is abundantly clear that "he" can only refer to "my father".